# Swift - Error decoding JSON "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api, swiftui

this my first time asking a question here, so please bear with me. Im using SwiftUI and im trying to fetch data from an API and store it in an array, i have 2 files as of right now:

MoviesFetcher.swift:

```
import Foundation

struct Movie: Codable {
    let original_title: String
    let releaseDate: String

}

var movieArray: [Movie] = []

class Fetcher {
    func fetchData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let urlString = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion()
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion()
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                completion()
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                movieArray = try decoder.decode([Movie].self, from: data)
                completion()
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
                completion()
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var movies: [Movie] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if movies.isEmpty {
                Text("Loading...")
            } else {
                List(movies, id: \.original_title) { movie in
                    Text(movie.original_title)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Fetcher().fetchData {
                movies = movieArray
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Given this, MoviesFetcher is where i have the code to try to fetch the data from "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=d2ea758c1787f6f8715df6713125a180" and store it in movieArray[].

Contentview is just accessing movieArray[] and trying to just show the title for each movie.

ERRORS: im getting this 2 errors in the debugging console

**Error decoding JSON: typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))**

**Error decoding JSON: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

It´s also my first year working with swift, so if anyone has better ways to do this, i will be very pleased and open to recommendations.

I haven´t tried much because i dont know any other way to do it.

Comment: Good point for using `do`/`try`/`catch` and printing the error (and not only its `localizedDescription`). Now, let's go a little further on debugging. Add a print on what's you are actually receiving: `print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)\nwith response stringified: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`, you should see then what's you've tried to decode. Could be show that your parsing is wrong, or that you have a completely different answer (because of request error or server error). And show us what's you're receiving

Comment: @Larme thanks for the reply, i just have 2 questions. 1- do you recommend that i should use another API given that in fact this api doesn't return various movies. 2- on the ContentView.swift file, i didn´t quite understand the switch statement inside of the VStack, what is it dependent on?

Comment: dude, remove your **secret** api_key from your post (in the https). Have a look at these posts, they
 will give you the answer to your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59315038/json-decoder-the-data-couldn-t-be-read-because-it-isn-t-in-the-correct-format/59315987#59315987  and  
 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62396033/tmdb-api-call-swift

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the API you are using returns only **one** movie and the code doesn't contain the API key.

This is a more native SwiftUI solution using `async/await` and a view model.

Declare the struct with lowerCamelCase names and an enum for the different states. Add the `id` member to get conformance to `Identifiable` for free.

```
struct Movie: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let originalTitle: String
    let releaseDate: String
}

enum LoadingState {
    case idle, loading, loaded([Movie]), failed(Error)
}
```

The view model adds the API key and set the states depending on the current phase. It runs on the main thread so you don't have to care about dispatching threads.

```
@MainActor
class Fetcher : ObservableObject {
    
    let apiKey = "••••••••••"
    
    @Published var state: LoadingState = .idle
    
    func fetchData() async  {
        state = .loading
        do {
            let url = URL(string:"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=\(apiKey)")!
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase // necessary to convert the names
            let movie = try decoder.decode(Movie.self, from: data)
            state = .loaded([movie])
        } catch {
            state = .failed(error)
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In the view create an instance of the view model and load the data in `.task`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var fetcher = Fetcher()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            switch fetcher.state {
                case .idle: EmptyView()
                case .loading: ProgressView()
                case .loaded(let movies):
                    List(movies) { movie in
                        HStack {
                            Text(movie.originalTitle)
                            Text(movie.releaseDate)
                        }
                    }
                case .failed(let error):
                    Text(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        .task {
            await fetcher.fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```